# Ajax.BeginForm OnSuccess not executed after Submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ajax.beginform

I am trying to use a jquery dialog to edit data in an WebGrid. Everythings works fine until the Form is submitted, instead of return to the current page that is open the browser goes to the url of the controller action. I am using an HTML.ActionLink in the WebGrid that adds jquery behavior to a button the WebGrid, and that works fine. It opens the View in a jquery dialog. The dialog defines two buttons: an update button and a cancel button. Clicking the cancel button does nothing. Clicking the update button takes the browser to the controller url for the edit action with the item id. I have the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js library defined and I added the UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled key in the Web.config file, although I am not sure it's needed. Has anyone experienced this behavior, any help is appreicated!

Comment: Code please before we can get any further with this.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this problem in two situations:

1. The event handler was not being
   binded to the form's submit event, or it was not suppressing the default behavior (through `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;`).
2. There was an error in the event
       handler, causing it to fall back to the
       default behavior.

Well this is how much I can try to help without any source.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue I wasnt referencing the jquery-Ajax.unobtrusive library so ensure that's there too

From my entry at http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/02/unobstrusive-javascript-in-mvc-3-helps.html

```
1. Set the mentioned flag in the web.config: <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
2. Include a reference to the jQuery library ~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js
3. Include a reference to the library that hooks this magic at ~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
```